# Decode raw Scapy data to human readable format

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

Decode raw Scapy data to human readable

`###[ Raw ]###`

`load = '\x01\x01{\x93\x00$\x01\x00\x03H\x04\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x14\x02\x00\x01\x03\x03D\x05\xfa\xab\xdd\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x02-\x00\x00\x01\x0f\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w>\x003w!\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x02-\x00\x00\x01\x0f\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d>\x00 \x8d!\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x02-\x00\x00\x01\x0f\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x02-\x00\x00\x01\x0f\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00!
None`

I want to convert this raw data to human readable format using scapy.

i tried using binascii module but i want it in scapy way (using any scapy method should be able to convert raw load data to human readable format)

I want to convert this raw data to human readable format using scapy.

Comment: You should provide much more context: where did you get this data from ? What have you tried so far ? Those are just bytes, it could be any Packet.. feel free to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get pro-tips on how to ask a good question on SO :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52260329/decode-raw-scapy-data-to-human-readable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode raw Scapy data to human readable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52260329/decode-raw-scapy-data-to-human-readable)